# Check if string is substring of another java

Tags: java, string

I need to use only length, substring and charAt methods of string to return a boolean if one string is a substring of another. I've tried a number of codes with various errors, the latest is an out of bounds error. I'd like some help to make my program do what i want. Below is my latest code

```
import java.util.*;
class subset
{   public static void main (String[]param)
{   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a long word");
    String large = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a shorter word");
    String small = sc.nextLine();       
    boolean isSubset = checkSubset(large, small);
    System.out.println(isSubset);       
}

public static boolean checkSubset(String large, String small)
{
    String word= "";
    boolean subset = false;
    if(large.length()<small.length())
    {   subset= false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<large.length();i++)
    {   for(int j=0; j<small.length();j++)
            {   if((large.charAt(i+j))==(small.charAt(j)))
                {   word= word+small.charAt(j);
                }
            }
    }
    if  (word.equals(small))
        {   subset=true;
        }

    return subset;
}
}
```

Comment: setting `subset` to `true` based on `'(large.length()<small.length())` seems odd. More importantly, since you can use it, you should really put `substring` to use.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I am trying to learn its use, but have found it hard to implement it to achieve my objective. I also forgot to change that before posting I was using it to test

Comment: If you can only use `length`, `substring` and `charAt`, then you're in violation when you use `equals`. Whether using `+` is also a violation is debatable. It can easily be done using only `length` and `charAt`, with no use of `substring`, `equals`, or `+`. I mean, why are you even building `word`, when you're already doing the char-by-char comparison? You just need to stop the `i` iteration at `large.length() - small.length()`, because any further than that can by definition not find a substring.

Comment: @Andreas Thats what I thought, I've tried not to use it. I mentioned it because it was allowed to be used

Comment: This would be much easier if you could use `indexOf()` method...

Comment: @Andreas thank you for explaining why to use 'large.length() - small.length()' . Also, I'm building word so that i may later compare it with small, and then return a boolean. Also the above fragment of code was all that was left to finish it. thank you for your time

Comment: *Why* do you need to compare `word` with `small` when you've already been comparing them char-by-char with the `charAt() == charAt()` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you move the inner loop into its own method. It will make the code more straightforward.

So, the inner loop will become this:

```
private static boolean subEquals(String large, int offset, String small) {
    for (int i = 0; i < small.length(); i++)
        if (large.charAt(offset + i) != small.charAt(i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

It checks to see if `small` equals the substring in `large` starting at `offset`.

You can then use that method in the outer loop of your code. Since that completes the test, you don't need `word` for anything.

```
public static boolean checkSubset(String large, String small) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= large.length() - small.length(); i++)
        if (subEquals(large, i, small))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Notice that the loop condition here is `<=`, not `<`.

Test of code:

```
System.out.println(checkSubset("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The"));
System.out.println(checkSubset("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "brown fox"));
System.out.println(checkSubset("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "dog"));
System.out.println(checkSubset("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "cat"));
```

generates this output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
String myLongSentence = "hello world it is a good day today";
String toFind = "world";

for(int i=0; i<myLongSentence.length()-(toFind.length()-1); i++) {
    System.out.println(myLongSentence.substring(i, (toFind.length()+i)));
}
```

Your code is too verbose for solving this problem.

Comment: Since there is no check for whether `toFind` is a substring in `myLongSentence`, how is this an answer to the question? You say that question code is "too verbose for solving this problem", but this is way too terse for solving this problem. And note that if the only allowed methods are `length`, `substring` and `charAt`, you can't use `equals` to compare the substring in this answer to the value of `toFind`.

Comment: He can just check in the for loop if they're equal. And the wording of OP in the comments make it seem confusing like he is allowed to use equals.

Answer (score 0):

Without going through your logic, the run-time error is possible because of large.charAt(i+j)

```
{   for(int j=0; j<small.length();j++)
        {   if((large.charAt(i+j))==(small.charAt(j)))
```

Assuming you were comparing something that was starting just before the end somethinglike large = "ThisIsALongWord" and small = "order".

The inner loop will continue to run starting from "ord" but the large array would have run out of index after the 3rd character.

Comment: The error was resolved, it was a for loop bound but the outer loop